# What's the equivalent of "RedirectMatch" from Apache using Traefik?

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to set up a frontend redirect using Traefik, but the docs don't explain how to do so.

I have an existing VirtualHost configuration in Apache that does this via:

```
ServerName jira.mycompany.com

RedirectMatch /.* https://mycompany.atlassian.net/
```

I *thought* that I should be able to do the same thing via my `routes.toml` file, like so:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.jira]
    backend = "jira"
    [frontends.jira.redirect]
    regex = "^https?://jira.mycompany.com/(.*)"
    replacement = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/$1"
[backends]
  [backend.jira]
    [backend.jira.servers.primary]
    url = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net"
```

However, trying to connect to https://jira.mycompany.com gives me an SSL protocol error.

`curl -v` tells me the following:

```
Toms-iMac:~ tgolden$ curl -v https://jira.mycompany.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://jira.mycompany.com/
*   Trying <external IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to jira.mycompany.com (<external IP>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

What am I missing here?

I tried adding a "Host:jira.mycompany.com" rule as well as SSLRedirect and SSLTemporaryRedirect headers as well -- no dice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the SSL error was due to my Traefik configuration using the deprecated `acme.ondemand` parameter. For an unrelated reason, the ACME challenge failed when trying to get a certificate for `jira.mycompany.com`, which caused the SSL handshake to fail.

I'm surprised the failed challenge for ondemand wouldn't fall back to the self-signed Traefik cert, but since the parameter was deprecated it shouldn't be as surprising.

Once I resolved this issue (ignoring the cert issue for the moment) the redirect worked as expected.